# How can I make a list of steps not repeat in a recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion

The output of the code is 1,1, 2,2 3,3, 4,4, instead of 1, 2, 3, 4. I tried a lot of different placements for the a variable to make it work, but this is the closest I have gotten it. Am I just misunderstanding something fundamental about recursion?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TowerOfHanoi {

    public static int a = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TowerOfHanoi towerOfHanoi = new TowerOfHanoi(); 

        System.out.println("Enter number of disks: ");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int disks = scan.nextInt();

        towerOfHanoi.solve(disks, "1", "2", "3");

        scan.close();
    }



    public void solve(int n, String start, String mid, String end){

        if(n == 1){

            System.out.println(a + " : "+ start + " to " + end);

            a++;

        } else {
            solve(n-1, start, end, mid);

            System.out.println(a + " : " + start + " to " + end);

            solve(n-1, mid, start, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 Enter number of disks: 
 3
 1 : 1 to 3
 2 : 1 to 2
 2 : 3 to 2
 3 : 1 to 3
 3 : 2 to 1
 4 : 2 to 3
 4 : 1 to 3
```

Comment: Can you show the whole output, and desired output? One thing is, you are calling `solve(n - 1, ...)` twice in each recursion until n equals one

Comment: Thank you Scott for fixing the output.

Comment: Because you're only incrementing a when you reach the bottom of the recursion (n == 1), and you're essentially drilling down to that before popping back to n == 2 to print and call solve again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of steps looks right to me, but you forgot to increment `a` in the `else` clause in `solve(...)`.

Solve should look something like this:

```
  public void solve(int n, String start, String mid, String end) {
    if (n == 1) {
      System.out.println(a + " : "+ start + " to " + end);
      a++;
    } else {
      solve(n-1, start, end, mid);
      System.out.println(a + " : " + start + " to " + end);
      a++;
      solve(n-1, mid, start, end);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`a` should be incremented after each `println`, not just the first.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why, that would be really helpful.

Comment: `a` is used to count steps; each `println` is a step.